# Laravel deleting a record affects the ordering of new records

Tags: laravel, eloquent, record

I successfully can delete a ticket and the record is removed from the database. If I have two tickets "Ticket 1 and Ticket 2", I can happily delete ticket 1 because its the FIRST ticket and can delete ticket 2 because its the next ticket after ticket 1 (In any order!)

However, I have a funny old problem where if I don't delete the tickets in a descending consecutive order

Take these tickets as an example:

Ticket 1 - Time created at 10:00
Ticket 2 - Time created at 10:15
Ticket 3 - Time created at 10:30

So, if I delete ticket 3 (because that was the last created ticket), delete ticket 2, delete ticket 1 and instead delete the middle ticket 'Ticket 2' I receive an error when trying to create another ticket. The new ticket is created however the 'author' and 'organisation' fields are not populated and when I go to open the ticket I get a 'No message error' -- because the ticket has failed to create fully.

When this new ticket is created with the empty 'author' and 'organisation' fields as well as the 'no message' laravel error, the ID gets added one above the one that was originally below it. So for instance, if I delete ticket 2 which has an id of 2 (leaving only tickets with id 1 and 3 left), when i create another ticket, it receives an ID of 4 which is correct, but in phpMyAdmin the 4 is showing above the 3 instead of being after the 3 of course. Also the 'slug' attribute of the ticket with ID '3' gets incremented to 'ticket-title-2" which also should not happen. However, I don't think it's related to the slug increment because without the method (as shown in ticket model) the problem still persists.

I also thought it was to do with the method of deleting I was using, so tried $ticket->forceDelete() instead of $ticket->delete(), but that did not seem to work. I tried going over my create method but after many hours of debugging I'm still struggling to find where this problem goes wrong. I DO KNOW however that the problem is to do with the ordering of a ticket when it is deleted, but where this problem is triggered I do not know.

Route

```
Route::delete('ticket/{ticket}', 'AdminController@delete')->name('admin.delete');
```

Ticket - store function

```
public function store()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->organisation == "Bournemouth University") {
            $ticketCode = "BU";
        } else {
            $ticketCode = "NHS";
        }

        $attributes = request()->validate([
            'title' => ['required', 'min: 2'],
            'description' => ['required'],
            'subject_area' => ['required']
        ]);

        Ticket::create($attributes);
        $slug = str_slug(Ticket::get()->last()->title, '-');

        Ticket::get()->last()->update(['code' => $ticketCode, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'slug' => $slug, 'author' => Auth::user()->username]);

        $slug = Ticket::get()->last()->slug;

        return redirect()->route('ticket.show', $slug);
    }
```

Admin controller - delete method

```
public function delete(Ticket $ticket){
        $ticket->delete();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Ticket page - delete form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h4>Are you sure you want to delete this post?</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form id="delete-post" method="POST" action="{{route('admin.delete', $slug->slug) }}">
                                            @csrf
                                            @method('DELETE')
                                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
                                                        id="confirm-del" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                        style="font-weight: bold;">Yes
                                                </button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                        style="font-weight: bold;">No
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            $(function(){
                                                $('#confirm-del').on('click', function(){
                                                    $('#delete-post').submit();
                                                });
                                            });
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Ticket model - slug increment methods

```
 public function setSlugAttribute($value){
        if(static::whereSlug($slug = str_slug($value))->exists()){
            $slug = $this->incrementSlug($slug);
        }

        $this->attributes['slug'] = $slug;
    }

    public function incrementSlug($slug){
        $firstSlug = $slug;
        $count = 2;

        while(static::whereSlug($slug)->exists()){
            $slug = "{$firstSlug}-" . $count++;
        }
        return $slug;
    }
```

Apologies if I'm quite unclear. I hope somebody can point me in the right direction to where I may be going wrong or how to rectify this issue.

Comment: Can you post your ticket model. Are you using the `softDeletes` trait? Is phpMyAdmin sorting the table by a particular field (causing records to be at the top when created)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it solves your problem, but each time you write

```
Ticket::get()->last()
```

You are making a large database query. Indeed, this translates as "get me all the results, and in the results you got, get me the last one". If you wanted to get the latest (by created_at order), you could use :

```
Ticket::latest()->first()
```

But then this is also one query each time you call it.

For several reasons (including concurrency, speed, maintainability), I would suggest making it all in one go :

```
public function store()
{
    if (Auth::user()->organisation == "Bournemouth University") {
        $ticketCode = "BU";
    } else {
        $ticketCode = "NHS";
    }

    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'title' => ['required', 'min: 2'],
        'description' => ['required'],
        'subject_area' => ['required']
    ]);

    // Now, populate the attributes before creating the ticket.
    $attributes['slug'] = str_slug(Ticket::get()->last()->title, '-');
    $attributes['code'] = $ticketCode;
    $attributes['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
    $attributes['author'] = Auth::user()->username;

    $ticket = Ticket::create($attributes);

    // And we get the slug directly from the ticket
    return redirect()->route('ticket.show', $ticket->slug);
}
```

PS : 
More improvement to this code could be :

- Use events to set the slug, not mutators.
- Use a relationship between users and tickets and remove the username field.